# IBM's Watson Assistant has stopped responding

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, watson-assistant

Just over a year ago I created a chatbot using IBM Watson Assistant. It is successfully interfacing with wordpress and facebook. it was working perfectly well in a web page too, but has now stopped outputting any text. I created the website integration by copying the code shown in the "preview link" page created by IBM when the bot is under development. That code includes a library file called "chat.0.0.4.js" and corresponding css. When the code runs now, the chatbot renders correctly, but when I look at the browser console I see at line 12990 in chat.0.0.4.js:

400 - {"error":"Invalid Request Body","errors":[{"message":"When source.type is not 'watson', source.id is required

Does anyone know how to fix this? I see that the integration code from the "preview link" is now totally different and I wonder if the mechanism I used a year ago is now depreciated?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is your chatbot located and when was it created? Did you check this page? https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-deploy-web-link IBM offers a dedicated website integration which is different from the preview: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-deploy-web-chat

Comment: It's in the UK. This is the invocation script:   <script>
    const config = {
      bot_image: 'icon-white.png', // 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/pix.iemoji.com/images/emoji/apple/ios-11/256/smiling-face-with-open-mouth.png'
      bot_name: 'SupaMoov Virtual Assistant',
      debug: true,
      element: document.querySelector('.Chat__body'),
      integration_id: 'xxxx....xxxxx',
      post_url: 'https://assistant-chat-eu-gb.watsonplatform.net/public/message/'
    };
    const chat = new WatsonChat(config); Thanks for the link I'll take a look.

Comment: The website integration there is either the preview link code as one option or a "proper" website integration only available to paying customers (plus and premium), I'm running the free version at the moment as my website is under development and the number of interactions will be small for some time to come. Are you suggesting I take the preview page code and edit it down for my own website? That's what I did last time and it's stopped working now. I've searched for a proper (and free) integration and can't fInd one anywhere. I must be missing something obvious!

Comment: Custom integration and the preview work in the Lite (free) plan and can be used for a website. Not sure if you can use this one: https://integrations.us-south.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/web/developer-documentation?to=

Comment: Its worth checking the security process you are using to connect to the Watson Assistant api's. IBM Cloud has been moving a lot of services from the old user/password to apikeys, and finally IAM process.

Comment: Many thanks @data_henrik I have managed to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the newer version, the script to integrate WA has changed and now looks like this:

```js
<script>
  window.watsonAssistantChatOptions = {
      integrationID: 'YOUR_INTEGRATION_ID',
      region: 'YOUR_REGION', 
      serviceInstanceID: 'YOUR_SERVICE_INSTANCE',
      onLoad: function(instance) { 
        instance.updateUserID(L12345);
        instance.render(); 
        }
    };
  setTimeout(function(){
    const t=document.createElement('script');
    t.src="https://web-chat.global.assistant.watson.appdomain.cloud/loadWatsonAssistantChat.js";
    document.head.appendChild(t);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Khalil, That's very similar to the code I ended up with.